# How to connect to DB before execution of bootstrap in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

i want to reroute url's from db table. Rerouting is (oh well should) be done in bootstrap class _intRoute function, where i call another function from Db Model but without db connection i get big error. So how i could force ZF connect to db earlear or maybe there is other methods to reroute url from db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you have the database and the modul resources (for resolving the model classes) already bootstraped. This might look like (draft only :):

```
function _initRoutes()
{
    $this->bootstrap('database');
    $this->bootstrap('modules');

    $model = new Default_Model_Route();
}
```